# Which Python3 lib for graphics?

Tags: python, python-3.x, graphics, python-imaging-library

I've been slowly learning Python over the past couple months and I'm currently building some  scripts for work that I'd like to turn into an application at some point.

What I need to do is import something that will build graphics.  For example, I need to build geometric shapes, fill them with color, and draw within them, possibly even load PNG files on top of them. It's for an icon set, but it would potentially build 20,000 or so icons, based on variables. Then it would save the generated graphic to an external file.

If anybody is familiar with MIL-STD-2525C, I'm trying to build a python-based generator for the SIDC symbols. So, suggestions for what libraries, native or third-party, to import? Please, no turtle. :)

Comment: have you looked at PIL (Python Imaging Library)? It also has a draw module.

Comment: I've looked into Pillow, but not PIL. I'll read into it more. I need something simple and straightforward. Nothing too crazy. Thanks!

Comment: Pillow and PIL are the same. Pillow is just a 'newer' version of PIL. You should have a look at the ImageDraw module of PIL: http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagedraw.htm

Comment: Just so you know, SO is for code questions, not 'software recommendation' questions.  I am not voting to close this time because a) your recommendation request is unusually well focused, and b) you have gotten 2 sensible answers with no flaming or 'religious' debate.

Comment: "A specific programming problem, or
a software algorithm, or
software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development..." According to OS' s FAQ these are reasons why folks post. I'd like to think my question is more than applicable to this site! Please don't try and make me an easy target just because I'm a new poster! I will defiantly follow the rules, though. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Cairo](http://cairographics.org/pycairo/).

It's a 2d graphic library with an easy-to-use API. It supports SVG documents and PostScript. So it should be ideal for icons and pictograms.

Comment: I'll give it a look. I'd up vote, but I don't have the rep yet!

Comment: I concur. I did something similar, with pycairo. It can beautifully render antialiased graphics. For examples, see https://github.com/luismqueral/jumpcityrecords